# How to keep the git blame relevant on files moved from one repo to another?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I frequently want to ask whoever wrote a function a question, but now I can't without back referencing the archive mono repo because the original history all belongs to the one guy who moved the files over "incorrectly". (Just in quotes because there's no issues I see except the git blame)

It would be very useful to retain git blame information from the old repo where the files originated. Is this possible? There have been many commits and refactorings since the original copy to another repo was made. The old repo is a useful archive mono-repo reference and not used at this point.

I believe it would have been possible if the original move was done by overwriting origin/master with the new repo location, as I've done this before and it kept history. But now that so much work has been done on it, I don't know how to resolve the issue.

Potential idea:

1. Clone or worktree the archival mono-repo
2. Find exact commit with desired history from archival repo that was used to start the new repo
3. Check out new branch recover_blame to do merging work in
4. Change origin/master remote to point to the new repo
5. I believe the only option here is to rebase master onto branch recover_blame? Merge won't recover the original git blame?

I believe there is a huge caveat with rebasing master in that it will completely screw up everyone with branches off of it, won't it? It breaks the golden rule of rebasing, don't rebase a branch someone else has already started working off. I think this would work if we all agreed to it and did it, but there's never going to be a good time to do it. Is there a safer way to get the blame history back without breaking everyone?

Answer (score 0):

One way : use `git replace`

- add the old repo as a remote
- fetch
- `git replace [first new commit] [old matching commit]`

Comment: I did the git replace, and it didn't error, but I don't see what it did or what I'm supposed to do now. I see it added a replace ref which means future git commands to that commit actually use the other commit.

Comment: `gco replace/551ff8e -- lib; git commit -c replace/551ff8e --reset-author` Didn't work. Blame all gets put on me. If I don't do the reset author, git blame entirely gets put on the person in the commit, rather than all the respective individual contributors of the lib.